# BASH - Removing everything before a specified character (script to run on Windows)

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I have a lot of files in a folder with the following format:

Node0123_RL2581_GS2001.jpg

I want to remove everything **before** the "**RL**" so it will be:

RL2581_GS2001.jpg

Note that the number of characters before the "RL" varies between 8 and 9 characters.

Thank you for any advice! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`bash`** solution:

```
for f in *_RL*.jpg; do mv "$f" "RL${f#*_RL}"; done
```

---

- `${f#*_RL}` - truncate the left part of the string(filename) till encountering `_RL` (including)

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong as it is not working :/

echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /D C:\Users\A\Desktop\A_tests\


for f in *_RL*.jpg; do mv "$f" "RL${f#*_RL}";
done

Comment: Nothing happens... :(

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for the help! It was a version problem as it seems to work perfectly on the PC this script will actually be used! ;)